# Does my Integrated Graphics still use power (watts) if I install a dedicated Graphics Card?

Tags: graphics-card

If I install a dedicated graphics card, for example: GTX1050ti. Which draws 75 watts at Maximum Graphics Card Power.

This means that the on-board integrated graphics is going to be disabled.

Is the integrated graphics still drawing the 20 watts it is rated at even though it is not being used?

If not, can I count that 20 watts towards the dedicated graphics card power?

I have a Small Form Factor HP with only a 240w psu, so power is critical.

Putting a bigger PSU in is not an option.

Comment: Brother, if your fumbling over each and every watt being used in your computer. I highly recommend you don't upgrade your computer until you can build a proper computer that can support a 500 watt PSU at least. I don't understand why "putting a bigger PSU is not an option" That should be the real question here. Why is it not an option? I find it hard to believe there isn't a PSU of whatever size your computer is that has a higher capacity.

Comment: Just because your Graphics card draws 75 watts max, doesn't mean anything. What about the rest of your computer? What kind of CPU do you have? What is the TDP? How much power does it draw when it's at 100% usage? How many hard drives do you have, each drive takes up power as well.

Comment: Also GTX1050ti: Minimum System Power Requirement (W) - 300

Answer (score 0):

You are referring here to
[Nvidia Optimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus),
defined as :

> Nvidia Optimus is a computer GPU switching technology created by Nvidia which, depending on the resource load generated by client software applications, will seamlessly switch between two graphics adapters within a computer system in order to provide either maximum performance or minimum power draw from the system's graphics rendering hardware.

This reduces power draw by disabling the discrete GPU whenever it is not needed.
By its nature, this GPU draws much more power than the integrated GPU,
so disabling it reduces power usage.

Now for the bad news. The Nvidia
[Optimus Whitepaper](https://www.nvidia.com/object/LO_optimus_whitepapers.html)
has this paragraph:

> Using NVIDIA‟s Optimus technology, when the discrete GPU is handling all the rendering duties, the final image output to the display is still handled by the Intel integrated graphics processor (IGP). In effect, the IGP is only being used as a simple display controller, resulting in a seamless, flicker-free experience with no need to reboot.

My understanding is that the discrete GPU is not directly connected to the screen
and requires the integrated GPU for this task.

This means that you may have only two states:

1. The integrated GPU is working and the discrete GPU is disabled and not drawing
   any power, or
2. Both GPUs are enabled and cooperating in display.
   The integrated GPU is used as a simple display adapter, so may draw somewhat
   less power, but this is not guaranteed.

The answer then seems to be that in your case,
when the discrete GPU is enabled,
power draw may reach 75+20=95 watts.